# expected expression, got '<' when route in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, pushstate, expected-exception

Am changing my routing hash route to Pushstate Route.
All route working except Parameter routing

When am calling ("/profile-page/:Id") kind of routing the error expected expression, got '<' comes in loop.

---

```
        }, {
            url: '/dashboard',
            config: {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                settings: {
                    nav: 3,
                    content: '<i class="fa fa-lock"></i> dashboard'
                }
            }
        }, {
            url: '/profile-page/:Id',
            config: {
                title: 'Profile-Page',
                templateUrl: 'app/profile-page/profile-page.html',
                settings: {
                    nav: 4,
                    content: '<i class="fa fa-lock"></i> profile-page'
                }
            }
        }
```

---

1. I am put all js library in body tag but not work.

Please Help .If you need more information Please reply .
Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried number for `:Id` like `/profile-page/1`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/biondifabio/95wEL/

Comment: Yes, we are try for number.